# Чёрный экран при запуске пк, Speaker пищит 4 длинных раза

Tags: компоненты, пк

При запуске Пк сразу начинает пищать Speaker 4 длинных раза, потом молчание секунды 2 и снова и так бесконечно. По признакам - ОЗУ, я купил новую ОЗУ и во все входы менял. Мать тоже новая, блок питания новый. Комп запускался 1 раз по неведомой причине, а затем снова все время чёрный экран и писк.

Comment: Смотрите документацию вашей материнской платы: в ней описаны звуковые сигналы. У каждой материнки они индивидуальные.

Comment: Ну типо смотрел ОЗУ или куллер, но все исправно, ОП специально даже после начала ошибки новую купил

Comment: Ещё раз: смотрите документацию вашей материнки. У **каждой** материнки индивидуальные звуковые сигналы. Никто не сможет вам сказать причину ошибки. Если у вас нет никакой инструкции (в бумажном виде или на CD), то вбейте название и модель материнки в любой поисковик или прямо на сайт производителя идите.